# How to set \mathscr to be like "boondoxo" of "mathalpha" while using "unicode-math"?

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

My font setup below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[Scale=0.93]
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[Scale=0.93,
range={up/{latin,Latin,num}, it/{latin,Latin,num},
    bfup/{latin,Latin,num}, bfit/{latin,Latin,num}}]
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\begin{document}
\[\mathscr{H}\]
\end{document}
```

prints `\mathscr{H}` like

[image]

which is a bit italic. But, I want it to be like the effect of

```
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
```

which looks like

[image]

How should I set up `unicode-math` to get it?

```
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr}]{?}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `\mathscr` of `Garamond-Math` almost does the job. However, its default looks a touch more slanted than what you probably want. So, applying a little bit of negative fake slant yields:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[Scale=0.93]
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[Scale=0.93,
range={up/{latin,Latin,num}, it/{latin,Latin,num},
    bfup/{latin,Latin,num}, bfit/{latin,Latin,num}}]
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\setmathfont[range={\mathscr}, FakeSlant=-0.3]{Garamond-Math}

\begin{document}
\[\mathscr{H}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You get the exact `boondoxo` font by borrowing the relevant code from `mathalpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[Scale=0.93]
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[
  Scale=0.93,
  range={
    up/{latin,Latin,num},
    it/{latin,Latin,num},
    bfup/{latin,Latin,num},
    bfit/{latin,Latin,num}
  }
]

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1] BOONDOX-r-calo}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{b}{n}{<-> s*[1] BOONDOX-b-calo}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mathscr\relax
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{m}{n}%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-calo}{b}{n}%
}

\begin{document}

$H\mathscr{H}$

$A\mathscr{A}B\mathscr{B}$

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLM}$

$\mathscr{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left `s*[1]` (which is actually redundant) in case you want to adjust the magnification factor.

Answer (score 1):

[Stylistic Set 1 of STIX Two Math](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/fonts/stix2-otf/STIXTwoMath-Regular.pdf) is a clone of Boondoxo.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % Or any other.
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={scr, bfscr}, StylisticSet=1, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathscr{ABCDEFGH} \\
  \mathbfscr{ABCDEFGH}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]