How would a "pro" LaTeX user improve my preamble/template?
First of all, sorry for this question: it might appear unusual, maybe it will be super downvoted but I take all my responsibilities in this.
What I am asking with this question is: what would a professional LaTeX user change in my preamble? What advice would one give me? What improvement could one give me?
Everyday I try to improve it myself, searching for tips, tricks, different fonts or styles, try to understand why things do work and/or why they don't.
I'm arrived at this point where I would love to hear some opinions, like a thesis review (to say so); advises, suggestions...
Thank you so much!
P.s. I also have one particular question about my template, but I'll ask it after having written the code.
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}


%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
%\setmainfont{Erewhon Regular}


\usepackage[cal=boondox]{mathalfa}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcalla} {symbols}


\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for a beautiful version of the italic "L" letter
\usepackage{mathtools} % it loads amsmaths too

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{verbatim} %for "begin comment"

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{E}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}
\definecolor{pine}{rgb}{0.0, 0.47, 0.43} 
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}

\usepackage{everysel}
\everymath{\color{E}}
\everydisplay{\color{E}}
\EverySelectfont{\color{black}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\lim}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\max}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\min}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\inf}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\sup}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\sum}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\prod}{\limits}{}{}

\apptocmd{\bigcup}{\limits}{}{}
\apptocmd{\bigcap}{\limits}{}{}


\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, cleveref}

\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise,1]{wide=0pt,
    label=\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\thesection.\arabic*\hspace{-0.5mm}}}}
          

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\the\numexpr\c@section-1\relax}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{}{0em}{}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{"Immagini/"}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pspicture}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{\textcolor{E}{tg}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcth}{\text{arctanh}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{\text{arcsinh}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{\text{arccosh}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{\text{\textcolor{E}{rk}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{\textcolor{E}{arctg}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{\textcolor{E}{End}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\spann}{\text{\textcolor{E}{span}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inside}{\textcolor{E}{int}}


%%% this is to use skipitems %%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skipitems}[1]{%
\addtocounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\nota}{\textbf{Nota:\ }}
\newcommand{\fatto}{\textbf{Fatto:\ }}
\newcommand{\oss}{\textbf{Osservazione:\ }}
\newcommand{\theo}{\textbf{Teorema.\ }}
\newcommand{\deff}{\textbf{Definizione.\ }}

\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{\(#1 _ #2\)} %for label in double enumerate

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}



\end{document}

The Question.
With this template, because of this part:
\usepackage{everysel}
\everymath{\color{E}}
\everydisplay{\color{E}}
\EverySelectfont{\color{black}}

I am not able to use the \begin{split} environment, nor the \begin{align}.
Is there a solution for this? A solution that doesn't require to delete my choice to have every math part in the colour I defined of course.
Thank you so much for this, I will appreciate any answer, idea, comment, tip.

you are loading too many packages and I assume that for a number part you do not know why.  Eg. why are you loading at least three symbol packages? And do not load everysel, as the package says it is no longer needed.

I'd start from removing the parts where you add \limits everywhere.

@UlrikeFischer Actually I know every package I'm using. But I also realize that I don't know if some of them are really useless or not. Well maybe the last ones they are now that I think about

@egreg If I remove that part, all the subscripts (in the limits, big cup, bigcap etc) are no longer under the operator, they are ugly and occupy more space

always start from an empty preamble and just add things you need,, it seems highly unlikely you are using all those font packages in a single documement, I would definitely avoid redefining standard commands, so all the limits additions look wrong, you could use environment hooks to add color rather then the everymath primitive, would be safer for ams alignments

@DavidCarlisle I wrote a PDF with basically 700 exercises, I can assure I need almost them all. I cut \everysel and \Everyselectfont for example. What do you mean with using envoronment hooks for colors? The everymath looked comfortable, everythime I use ( ) I don't have to add anything else

@Henry With \limits you completely spoil the line spacing.

well you asked for comments and more or less three of us said the same, but it's your document your choice.  You are misusing inline math. pspicture seems an odd choice these days(despite the fact I wrote it)

the whole point of inline math is to set the math in line ie not disturbing the paragraph line spacing. Your limits definitions destroy that

\EverySelectfont{\color{black}} seems very strange why do you need to re-assert black on every font selection? This is adding a lot of spurious color nodes into the document

@DavidCarlisle Thank you! Indeed I removed \EverySelectfont... Also I know that I am disturbing the line spacing with \limits, but well this will stay because it's rather useful to compactify the writing. About pspicture, you're right. Didn't notice actually haha, removed!

and are you using both pstricks and tikz both are fine packages, but most documents use one or the other. Using \everymath{\color means for example that every tabular is coloured, is that intended?

@DavidCarlisle Yes, that is intended! About pstricks and tikz, I noticed that it's better to use them both. Thank you again!

I believe this belongs to [codereview.se] with a TeX tag. I have asked for suggestions for my code long ago and I think you can still get active response there. At least high-rep users like egreg will be there.

@WeijunZhou Thank you! Should I ask a new question there?

@Henry Maybe not this time unless you can formulate your new question in a quite different way. Cross-site dupes are frowned upon. However, make sure you ask on the correct site next time.

The answers now give some excellent specific points; but for relevant general advice, see my answer to this old near-duplicate question

My recommendation is: not to use LaTeX at all. Use another TeX macro packages, for example OpTeX. Then you don't need to load tons of another subpackages.

TL;DR
My general rule of thumb has always been to keep things as simple as possible. I follow the KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid) principle: avoid spending too much time on making the document look overly polished. Instead, focus on clarity and readability. I recommend avoiding unnecessary packages and only including them when absolutely necessary, especially when it comes to fonts and redefining commands. This approach helps minimize or avoid compatibility issues.
"always start from an empty preamble and just add things you need" @David Carlisle
Also related: this reply to the question "Is this a junk preamble?".
"start with nothing in your preamble apart from the essential document setup (\documentclass, \title, etc), and then when you find yourself missing some feature you liked from the preamble you were using, try to work out which package/command(s) gave that feature, and add it to your new version" @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine
I have revised and expanded the reply to address all the raised issues, giving credit to those who reported them.
1. Handle warnings and errors
Simply loading this preamble in an empty document generates 9 warnings, and it’s best to keep things warning-free :)
If you are aware of the warning/error but don't plan to address it, it is simply noise. In that case, silencing it is the appropriate approach. You can use the silence package for this.

quick tutorial on how to use the silence package: Silencing Warnings and Errors in LaTeX;

2. Use package options consistently
The geometry package
In the document class options, you've specified a4paper, yet later you ask the geometry package to set the paper size to 173mm by 257mm. This creates a bit of a mismatch between the two settings.
% \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
% \usepackage{geometry}
% \geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.7cm]{geometry}

The scrreport documentclass
Is there a particular reason you're using scrreport instead of the standard report class? It leads to compatibility issues with packages like titlesec and fancyhdr. You can either make use of KOMA-Script features, such as \setkomafont, \RedeclareSectionCommand, \sectionlinesformat, and others, to customize section headings, or you could simply switch to the standard report class.
% \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

The cleveref package
As @cfr reported "you are loading italian, you don't seem to be telling the class or any other package about this. So cleveref, for example, may use American English in some unexpected places. Better to add italian to your class options."
\usepackage[noabbrev, italian]{cleveref}


ensure coherence with the options specified for the packages;
load the package cleveref last, as it tells you in the documentation;

The xcolor package
Related discussions:

When to use the xcolor package instead of the color package?
Option clash for package xcolor

The option usenames is obsolete.
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


load the xcolor package early with all the necessary options to avoid conflicts, as it is also used by other packages;

3. Consult the documentation to identify obsolete packages
The physics package
See related discussions:

Alternatives to the physics package;
Physics replacement effort and the community wiki reply.

% \usepackage{physics}


explore alternatives to the physics package and refrain from using it in newer documents;

The everysel package
As @Ulrike Fischer reported in the comments: "do not load everysel, as the package says it is no longer needed".
The everysel package also disrupts the split environment.
% \usepackage{everysel}
% \everymath{\color{VividBerry}}
% \everydisplay{\color{VividBerry}}
% \EverySelectfont{\color{black}}

The tabularx package
Related discussions: Optimising tabularray tables (tblr and longtblr) for processing speed
The tabularx package is preferred for Overleaf users due to its faster compilation times and suitability for straightforward use cases. For more complex needs, the tabularray package provides a clear distinction between table content and style, with styling managed through a key-value configuration system.
@cfr: "for overleaf users, defining all tables using this package is a recipe for exceeding compilation time limits. I'd recommend using older packages for simple cases."
% Recommended for simple cases and Overleaf users due to faster compilation
\usepackage{tabularx}
% Suitable for complex cases, but with longer compilation times
\usepackage{tabularray}

4. Don't reinvent the wheel
The etoolbox package
\limits is a TeX primitive; avoid using it globally, as it can completely disrupt the line spacing, as @egreg mentioned in the comments.
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \apptocmd{\lim}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\max}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\min}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\inf}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\sup}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\sum}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\prod}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\bigcup}{\limits}{}{}
% \apptocmd{\bigcap}{\limits}{}{}

The titlesec package
Why remove numbers from sections at all? You can simply use the starred version: \section*{section name}.
% \usepackage{titlesec}

% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand\thesection{\the\numexpr\c@section-1\relax}
% \makeatother

% \titleformat{\section}[runin]
% {\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{}{0em}{}

Theorems and proofs
Latex defines these environments see Theorems and proofs.
% \newcommand{\nota}{\textbf{Nota:\ }}
% \newcommand{\fatto}{\textbf{Fatto:\ }}
% \newcommand{\oss}{\textbf{Osservazione:\ }}
% \newcommand{\theo}{\textbf{Teorema.\ }}
% \newcommand{\deff}{\textbf{Definizione.\ }}

Why define deff when most editors offer autocompletion? Also, consider the importance of using meaningful names for variables, as mentioned further below.
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definizione}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fatto}
\newtheorem{note}{Nota}
\newtheorem{observation}{Osservazione}


look for standard commands instead of defining your own, as this makes it easier to identify what you're doing;

The mathtools package
See @David Carlisle reply.
% \DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{\textcolor{VividBerry}{tg}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\arcth}{\text{arctanh}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{\text{arcsinh}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{\text{arccosh}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{\text{\textcolor{E}{rk}}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{\textcolor{E}{arctg}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\End}{\textcolor{E}{End}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\spann}{\text{\textcolor{E}{span}}}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\inside}{\textcolor{E}{int}}

Simplify the declarations:
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcth}{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{arccosh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rk}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spann}{span}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inside}{int}


avoid spending too much time on making the document look overly polished, and instead focus on clarity and readability;

5. Avoid using low-level TeX primitives
I'm sure that you don't need to use low-level TeX primitives, see: How to skip an \item in sub-enumerate level.
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand{\skipitems}[1]{%
% \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
% }
% \makeatother

6. Avoid potential duplication
As @David Carlisle mentioned, multiple font and drawing packages are loaded. Please refer to his reply for further details.
Furthermore the pspicture package it has been superseded by the pict2e package. Personally, I would consider it obsolete nowadays.

using a more restricted and coherent font set may improve the document;
select a drawing package and consistently use it;
avoid loading a package multiple times, as it has no effect;
review the CTAN descriptions of packages, as they often indicate if a package is obsolete and provide details about its replacement;

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

7. Use only what you need
If all you need is the comment environment, why not just load the comment package?
% \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{comment}

8. Use meaningful mames for variables
If you name your variables with single letters, how can you be sure that "E" represents a color?
% \definecolor{E}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}
% \definecolor{pine}{rgb}{0.0, 0.47, 0.43} 
% \definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{VividBerry}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}
\definecolor{DeepAqua}{rgb}{0.0, 0.47, 0.43} 
\definecolor{StormyCharcoal}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}


this is a key principle for programmers: always use meaningful names for variables. Code for readability.

The new preamble
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

% use the new package 'tabularray' to define tables instead
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Multiple font packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{bbm}
% \usepackage{mathrsfs}
% \usepackage{wasysym} 
% \usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage[cal=boondox]{mathalfa}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcalla}{symbols}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{VividBerry}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}
\definecolor{DeepAqua}{rgb}{0.0, 0.47, 0.43} 
\definecolor{StormyCharcoal}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise,1]{%
    wide=0pt,
    label=\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\thesection.\arabic*\hspace{-0.5mm}}}%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
% you don't need double quotes to specify a path
\graphicspath{
    {Immagini/}
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcth}{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{arccosh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rk}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spann}{span}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inside}{int}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definizione}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fatto}
\newtheorem{note}{Nota}
\newtheorem{observation}{Osservazione}

% I don't understand why you should need such a thing
\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{\(#1_#2\)}% for label in double enumerate

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

% remember to load it last
\usepackage[noabbrev, italian]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Colors}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcolor{VividBerry}{VividBerry};
    \item \textcolor{DeepAqua}{DeepAqua};
    \item \textcolor{StormyCharcoal}{StormyCharcoal}.
\end{itemize}

\section{Split environment}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{split}
A & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
  & = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\section{New environment definitions}

\begin{theorem}
    Text of the Theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
    Text of the Definition
\end{definition}

\begin{fact}
    Text of the fact
\end{fact}

\begin{note}
    Text of the fact
\end{note}

\begin{observation}
    Text of the fact
\end{observation}

\end{document}


Thank you so much for all this, I will take a care look. Just another question, but don't feel forced to answer: as you can see, at the beginning of my preamble I commented three packages, which are unicode-math and the two successive ones. I was trying to make them work, but it keep giving me a machine error, and when I tried to compile in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX I keep getting a sort of incompatibility error with the boondox package. Is there something I can do to use it correctly (I just wanted to change font and style!)

The best approach would be to ask another question with a minimal working example (MWE) to help clarify the issue (as suggested here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). My assumption is that the packages may be incompatible, so it might be useful to check if this question (found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656929/) could provide a solution.

Unfortunately, I'm not an expert when it comes to font usage in LaTeX, but my general rule of thumb has always been to keep things as simple as possible. I follow the KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid) principle: avoid spending too much time on making the document look overly polished. Instead, focus on clarity and readability. I recommend avoiding unnecessary packages and only including them when absolutely necessary, especially when it comes to fonts and redefining commands. This approach helps minimize or avoid compatibility issues.

Happy to help! If this answer, or any other, solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Your answer is of great help! If I happen to have some more "curiosities" about your comments, I'll write here

@Henry, I have revised and expanded the reply if you'd like to have a look.

Oh my, this is just stunning. I am going to read it carefully. Thank you infinitely much!!

this is an excellent answer, but I would take issue with the claim that it is advisable to use tabularray in general. especially for overleaf users, defining all tables using this package is a recipe for exceeding compilation time limits. I'd recommend using older packages for simple cases. I would be far more concerned about the use of cleveref than tabularx. cc @Henry

I promptly update the response incorporating your suggestions :)

The preamble shows a lot of potential duplication:
Multiple font packages
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}

If you really use all these fonts in a single document these are fine, but using a more restricted and coherent font set may improve the document.
Multiple drawing packages:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pspicture}

There are better packages than pspicture these days and using tikz and pstricks in one document is unusual. Specifying pgf and tikz again does nothing as the first call to tikz will have already loaded both.
Several commands will destroy the inline math line spacing.
\apptocmd{\max}{\limits}{}{}

This will make \max unusable in inline math.
Packages with dubious definitions
\usepackage{physics}

I'd avoid this, personally.
Multiple spurious colour insertions
\EverySelectfont{\color{black}}

Will re-insert black every font change which is inserting a lot of spurious nodes.
Coloring all math
\everymath{\color{E}}

will color all internal uses of math mode for example tabular uses math to get centred alignment even if it appears purely as text mode in the document.
\everydisplay{\color{E}}

will insert a color node preventing math aligned displays, it would be better to use an environment hook  to add the color before it starts the primitive math display mode.
Misusing \text
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{\text{arcsinh}}

\text is for non-mathematical text and will pick up the text font current before the math start (so is typically italic in throrems for example) use \mathrm or in \DeclareMathOperator you need no command at all as the math rm font is assumed.

Why does tabular use math to get centered alignment? I'm just curious, since I use tabulararray everywhere now

@EmanueleNardi because \vcenter is tex's only built in mechanism for vertical centering and it is a math mode command you may not use tabular but the same is true of minipage or \parbox which are similarly math mode by default.

"Specifying pgf and tikz again does nothing as the first call to tikz will have already loaded both" Why does this matter? if at any point pgf decides to no longer load tikz, the document won't compile anymore. afair, in C++ it's good practice to not rely on "another include will load this for me". Why is this different in Latex?

@infinitezero it doesn't matter much but if someone asks for a code review and has multiple packages loaded then they are likely to get comments on that. We see here all the time preambles posted with teh same package often loaded multiple times because boilerplate text has been copied over and over with no thought to the actual document behaviour, so repeated package load is usually a sign of general issues in the document rather than being a major technical issue in itself.

@DavidCarlisle thanks for clarifying!

Additional points (unless I've missed them):

If you use cleveref, you should load it last, as it tells you in the documentation. There are some rare exceptions to this, but you should only load something later if you know it needs to be loaded later.
Although you are loading italian, you don't seem to be telling the class or any other package about this. So cleveref, for example, may use American English in some unexpected places. Better to add italian to your class options.
As far as I've seen the physics package can be problematic in itself.

Further to the discussion of drawing packages, it isn't clear why you say tikz and pstricks do better together. To use pstricks, you need to be using a workflow which is not incompatible with tikz, but also not really optimal. tikz generally works most easily with luaTeX or pdfTeX (where graph features need the former), whereas pstricks generally needs TeX + post-processing, XeTeX or LuaTeX. But if you are using LuaTeX (and possibly XeTeX), you would be better to use Unicode maths rather than the legacy 8bit setup your packages suggest.

Just a note, pstricks works with lualatex out-of-the-box too nowadays

@mbert thanks. is this better? (I've never actually used pstricks an don't use luatex either ....)

Yes but it might be confusing to say "X needs luatex or pdftex whereas Y needs luatex or ...". I'm not sure it's a problem to use tikz and pstricks at the same time. Some things like pst-marble or pst-geo would be difficult or impossible to do with tikz
